# Webscraping / Beautifulsoup / sometimes None-return?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i try to **scrape** some informations from a webpage and on the one page it is working fine, but on the other webpage it is not working cause i only get a none return-value

This code / webpage is working fine:

```
# https://realpython.com/beautiful-soup-web-scraper-python/
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.monster.at/jobs/suche/?q=Software-Devel&where=Graz"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

name_box = soup.findAll("div", attrs={"class": "company"})
print (name_box)
```

But with this code / webpage i only get a None as return-value

```
# https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-scrape-websites-with-python-and-beautifulsoup-5946935d93fe/

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/SPX:IND"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")


name_box = soup.find("h1", attrs={"class": "companyName__99a4824b"})
print (name_box)
```

Why is that?

(at first i thought due the number in the class on the second webpage "companyName__99a4824b" it changes the classname dynamicly - but this is not the case - when i refresh the webpage it is still the same classname...)

Comment: if you simply print the contents of `soup` to a notepad or to the console, do you still see this tag `companyName__99a4824b` and the text inside it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get `None` is that the Bloomberg page uses Javascript to load its content while the user is on the page.

`BeautifulSoup` simply returns to you the html of the page as found as soon as it reaches the page -- which does not contain the `companyName_99a4824b` class-tag.

Only after the user has waited for the page to fully load does the html include the desired tag.

If you want to scrape that data, you'll need to use something like [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html), which you can instruct to wait until the desired element of the page is ready.

Comment: Many thanks dear Peter - for the hint with JavaScript and that we need to run Selenium to get the information.

Comment: thanks for the clarification! i saw that there are two ways - one with scrapy and one with selenium - are there pros and cons for both ways?

Answer (score 0):

The website blocks scrapers, check the title:

```
print(soup.find("title"))
```

To bypass this you must use a real browser which can run JavaScript.
A tool called Selenium can do that for you.