# Scraping website with Python3 / AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to scrape a website but I keep getting `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'` error. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = 'https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/SPX:IND'    
page = urlopen(html)    
data = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')    
name_box = data.find('h1', attrs={'class': 'companyName__99a4824b'}) 
name = name_box.text.strip() 
print(name)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webscraping / Beautifulsoup / sometimes None-return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61185044/webscraping-beautifulsoup-sometimes-none-return)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scrap data from bloomberg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58064494/scrap-data-from-bloomberg)

Answer (score 0):

Your name_box is None hence the problem is in finding the h1 in line:

```
name_box = data.find('h1', attrs={'class': 'companyName__99a4824b'})
```

Maybe the class is not correct

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the output of your request (via `print(data)`) you can see your request was caught by their robot filter.

See: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58064494/scrap-data-from-bloomberg)